# How to convert number 1 to 1.00 in javascript and 1.00 must be typeof number?

Tags: javascript

```
var number = 1;

console.log( number.toFixed(2));
// "1.00"

console.log( typeof(number)) // "string"
```

But i want `1.00` as

```
console.log( typeof(number)) // number with decimal 1.00 and type should be number.
```

Comment: If it is a number, what's the difference between `1` and `1.00`?

Comment: What do you want to do with it that requires it to be a number?

Comment: `1` and `1.00` are the same thing.

Comment: You can not have trailing zeros without a string. JavaScript does not have significant digits.

Comment: Why would `typeof number` return string?

Comment: possible dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29321811/in-javascript-how-to-represent-1-00-as-a-number-in-a-json-object

Comment: Your code seems to be incorrectly pasted, as long as you do not cast like number.toFixed(2) to number it will stay a number. number.toFixed() returns a string and "1.00" is what your toFixed makes of 1 (=1.00 w/ quotes)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Javascript ,how to represent 1.00 as a number in a JSON object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29321811/in-javascript-how-to-represent-1-00-as-a-number-in-a-json-object)

Answer (score 0):

Javascript does not distinguish between integers and fixed point numbers. They are all Numbers. `1` and `1.00` are the same thing in a Number object. Output/ visual representation of the data in an object is up to you.

If you wish to show it or output it in JSON then you need to convert it to a string using the `toFixed` method or similar.

You should really state your question in terms of what you want to do with the `number` variable that requires two decimal places. In most cases the internal representation is irrelevant

Answer (score 0):

var number = 1;
console.log(number.toFixed(2));

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).